# WebSecurity fails to initialize SQL Azure connection

Tags: c#, azure, razor, webmatrix

I have a Razor website that uses the WebSecurity helper for authentication. Originally I had a file `Users.sdf` in App_Data which contained my user table for testing, but I am trying to move to Azure, so I deleted the .sdf, set up a SQL Azure database and added a connection string named "Users" to my Web.config.  I also added my IP address to the database firewall exceptions so that I could test locally.  However, when I try to run the site from WebMatrix, I get the following less-than-helpful error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Login failed for user '[username]'.
[...]
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user '[username]'
```

The "source error" section simply highlights the (previously working) call to `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` in _AppStart.cshtml.  The connection string is essentially exactly copied from the Azure database management portal, and I know the login information is correct because I've used it to access the database manually, so I'm not sure what could be going on.  I've seen a number of other SO questions with a similar problem, but they all seem to involve incorrect connection strings or are otherwise in a different context.

Below is all the code which I can imagine being relevant (since the failure happens in _AppStart), but let me know if there's anything else I should add:

*_AppStart.cshtml:*

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Users", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", true);
```

*Web.config:*

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Users" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
       connectionString="Data Source=tcp:xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;
                         Database=LoginUsers;
                         User ID=[username]@xxxxxxxxxx; Password=[password];
                         Trusted_Connection=False;
                         Encrypt=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: And as an aside, is there any actual reason to include `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in this setting, or is it unnecessary?

Comment: My own connection strings for Azure all use `Initial Catalog=`, rather than `Database=`. Everything else looks about the same. Give that setting a try.

Comment: I was wondering about that too, but I tried this and it still behaved the same.  I think we're talking to Azure support later this week though, so if they provide a solution at that point then I might be able to post my own answer.  Here's hoping!